# Multiple "or" conditions in "while loop"

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I am working on a school project (blackjack game)
Currently i am working on 'hit' 'stand'... options that the player has.

I am no Python guru, but i am pretty sure that this should work.

Please take a look at it and tell me where i go wrong.

While debugging i can see that the value of 'playerChoice' is correct when going in the 'while' loop.

```
playerChoice = ''

while playerChoice != 'split' or playerChoice != 'stand' or playerChoice != 'hit' 
or playerChoice != 'double down':
    playerChoice = input('(split, stand, hit, double down) : ')
```

I expect that when one of the statements is false we should got out of the 'while' loop and continue with the code execution, but instead the loop continues no matter the response

I know that i can come up with some sort of 'brake' inside the loop, but i was wondering why this doesn't work.

Comment: `while playerChoice.lower().strip() not in ['split', 'stand', 'hit', 'double down']`:

Comment: Mixing `or` and negatives, means the condition will always be true. `playerChoice != 'split' or playerChoice != 'stand'` If the choice is `split` it is not `stand` which makes the `or` as a whole true.

Comment: Net solution, thank you! Can you tell me why does mine not do what is should?

Comment: Your condition is always going to evaluate in a `bool or bool or bool or bool` expression. so if *any* of those are `True`, the loop continues. What you need is a condition that exits if *any* of those are false.

Comment: Got it, i should have went with 'and'. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @TsvetomirBatinov Or just switch your `!=` to `==`.  It may read better that way instead of changing `or` to `and`.  Also to do inline code in comments use the backtick (the one above the tab key). Also consider using DavidZemens notation as it is even more readable.